# IOS/Xcode: Breakpoint in completion block possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I am trying to debug something going on in a completion block.  I put a breakpoint in the completion block, but the code is not breaking.  Is it possible to put a breakpoint in a completion block?  I recall it being possible but cannot seem to find any confirmation in the docs or on the Internet.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                LogDebug(@"ready to save to database if this was new to server");

                Items *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:myMoID];
 //TRIED PUTTING BREAKPOINT RIGHT HERE BUT NOT STOPPING               
                if (successInt==1) {
                    object.needsync=@0;
                }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always put a breakpoint on a line where some code is, not an empty line, it works better.

If your log is not printed out in a console, it means your block is never called.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not breaking this means that your completion block is not being called. Try to print log in completion block to check that if it is being called or not.